# Web and Database server settings to get UTC timezone "right"

Tags: php, mysql, apache, utc

I'm overwhelmed trying to get this right:  We've got servers located across a dozen time zones, with Apache and MySQL running on all or some of them, as well as MySQL hosted on Amazon RDS.

I want to know "Best Practices", or how to otherwise configure each MySQL and PHP installation so that when a row is added to the database from PHP I'm certain that the value there is actually the UTC time when the event happened, regardless of *where* the server is located when it happened.  Presenting it to the user in any given timezone is not an issue - I just want to know that the datetime columns are actually storing the actual moment in time when something occurred.

As it is now, the Web Servers are set to whatever the local timezone is due to scheduled events, etc., and I'm not sure which parts of the puzzle use which settings from where to come up with whatever is written to the database.

I apologize if the question seems unclear, at this point I don't know what I don't know, so getting a precise question is even challenging.  Also, all our dates are in the database as DateTime fields, so storing timestamps isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you restrict yourself to MySQLs DATE and DATETIME types, you can largely ignore time zone issues in MySQL itself.  You want to avoid MySQL's TIMESTAMP type because:

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

As far as reading/writing DATETIME values, you'll get back exactly what you put in, which is good.

That leaves you with the problem of always ensuring you are writing UTC values to the database.

The best way to ensure that PHP is using UTC is to explicitly set it in your application using [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).  That will ensure that calls like `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` will give you the UTC value.  It will also ensure that something like `(new \DateTime('now'))->getTimezone()` will return a UTC \DateTimeZone instance.

You should note, of course, that things get significantly more difficult when you're storing date/time values that you take from users.  In those cases, you'll need to somehow determine what timezone the user is in, and handle conversion to UTC before persisting the values.  Assuming your users have some per-user timezone setting, you basically do something like:

```
/** @var \DateTimeZone $userTZ */
$userTz = getUserTimezone();
$dateTime = new \DateTime($user_submitted_date_string, $userTz);
$dateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTime('UTC'));
$dateTimeStr = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for..."ensure PHP is using UTC..." and I/we can control that at the application level.  As long as I know that UTC is going into the database, everything else is a piece of cake....THANK YOU

Comment: One last question...it seems that default-time-zone in MySQL has no bearing on any PHP, aside from SQL that use NOW(), CURDATE(), etc.  Is that the case?

Comment: @GDP - I'm wary of making such categorical statements.  But I'll say yes.  As long as you avoid MySQL functions that depend on MySQL's internal default-time-zone setting, you're good.  INSERT/SELECT behavior, in particular, is indistinguishable from that of VARCHAR columns.

Comment: That's the DB insight I need...thanks so much again...at least I know where I am on the map and can plot a course now.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple, always store unix [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)  in the database (or if you want microsecond accuracy with microtime ). Then regardless of the timezone of each of your webservers, if two of them recieve a request at the same time, it would be the same integer value that is saved in the database (the database field shoudl obviously be an int (or big int for micro time))

And how to display? Easy with javascript.

```
new Date(unix_timestamp);
```

This produces a date and time in the user's timezone.

Comment: Cannot agree strongly enough. The only place dates and times should ever be represented as strings is on the thin layer of pixels on the user's screen.

Comment: I apologize...I;ll clarify that all the data wer;e concerned about is stored as MySQL Datetime types

Comment: Also, not concerned about displaying, that's "simple".  Its knowing what PHP comes up with using date() vs, what MySQL defaults to with timestamps in concert with the timezones that are set in various server apps throughout the network.

Comment: yes, date time calculations in both mysql and php (and quite a few other languages that I have used) are painfully complicated. unix times takes away all that pain + the complications of dealing with timezones