# MySql CONVERT_TZ not working on time conversion day

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, timezone, convert-tz

I try to convert timezones from local format to UTC that works fine except in one case. At the day of conversion (27.03 02:00:00) and only when going from GMT+1 to GMT+2.
(The conversion back is at 30.10 at 03:00:00)

OK -> 
`SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2016-03-27 01:59:59','Europe/Vienna','UTC');`
GMT +1 = 00:59:59

BUG -> `SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2016-03-27 02:00:01','Europe/Vienna','UTC');`
GMT +2 = 01:00:00

Here the bug occurs, from 02:00:00 when its the time of conversion to 02:59:59, the hour doesn't convert and each given minute and second is ignored...

That means:
`02:00:00 -> 01:00:00`
`02:00:01 -> 01:00:00`
`02:59:59 -> 01:00:00`

at 03:00:00 the conversion is okay again...
OK -> `SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2016-03-27 03:00:00','Europe/Vienna','UTC');`
GMT +2 = 01:00:00

any ideas or experiences with this bug?

Comment: You're passing in local times that don't exist. I suggest you avoid doing that. (The local time would go 01:59:58, 01:59:59, 03:00:00... so asking what UTC time a local time of 02:00:00 maps to is a meaningless question.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877950/web-and-database-server-settings-to-get-utc-timezone-right/40878011#40878011

Comment: somehow obvious! thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web and Database server settings to get UTC timezone "right"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877950/web-and-database-server-settings-to-get-utc-timezone-right)