# timestamp shows wrong time in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, linux, centos

I have been facing the different timezone issues in reporting the data.
In order to change the timestamp, I've taken following steps.

1. Checked the time in mysql, its showing perfect time and timezone. I've checked with "date command".
2. running this: `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;` on mysql shows, +05:30 and +05:30.
3. `SELECT @@system_time_zone;` gives "IST" which is also correct.
4. I checked the php time by echo function which is also right, but I don't know why timestamp in database shows UTC time.

Comment: have you set the default time zone in php?

Comment: add/change `date.timezone = Asia/Calcutta` in you `php.ini` in the `[Date]` section. and don't forget to restart your web server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web and Database server settings to get UTC timezone "right"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877950/web-and-database-server-settings-to-get-utc-timezone-right)

Answer (score 0):

please change the timezone in php.ini file and restart your web server .