# phpMyAdmin SELECT UNIXTIMESTAMP vs PHP Query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, unix-timestamp

When  I do a SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field) in phpMyAdmin, the value I get is 1541577600.  When I do the same select in PHP on the same server, I get a value which is 3600 less (i.e. 1541574000).  What is it that causes this difference?

The field in question is a date in string format (2018-11-07).

The strange thing is that when I select current time in phpMyAdmin

SELECT CURRENT_TIME

it's perfect.

Comment: timezones, dst? Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009695/timestamp-shows-wrong-time-in-phpmyadmin) maybe

Comment: I think this might have been a transient issue because it occurred on the weekend of DST changeover.